# How to get coordinates of 4 points for UI.Button in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find out whether `UI.Button` is inside a `Rect` region or not.

As I am new to Unity, the only method I see is to check all 4 points of button's rectangular bounds to be in rectangular region, but I can't find this points.

I tried to get bounds from `Renderer` and from `Collider` via `gameObject.GetComponent<>.bounds`, but there is no renderer\collider attached to button. Besides that fact, I see no reason to create a renderer for button as the button is rendered somehow, hence there should be a method to achieve my goal without creating additional components.

How can I find button's bound points or check whether it is completely inside the region or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
public class ButtonOverlapTest : MonoBehaviour {

    RectTransform rectTransform;
    Rect otherRect = new Rect(20, 20, 100, 100);

    void Start()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    public void ButtonClicked()
    {
        if (rectTransform.rect.Overlaps(otherRect))
        {
            Debug.Log("Overlap!");
        }

    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Overlaps.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me to budge.
I tried what you suggested, but rect of `RectTransform` is in local coordinates, so I use `GetWorldCorners` and check whether they lie inside of the region.